# how to block a clickjacking

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how to stop any clickjacking attacks. I have some ideas since some people say to use the **"Frame Busting"** technique, while others say to act directly in the web.config and add the **X-FRAME-OPTIONS** tag.
Also, I would like to understand if the concept of clickjacking is exclusively related to the use of `<iframe>`.
Thank you very much